# check_cluster arguments aren't being parsed

Tags: nagios

trying to create a cluster check for a http service check on a large (~80 node) cluster. I'd like it to warn @ 40+ nodes in a non-ok state, crit @ 60+ nodes in a non-ok state.

command definition is:

```
define command {
command_name         check_cluster
command_line         $USER1$/check_cluster --service -l $ARG1$ -w $ARG2$ -c $ARG3$ -d $ARG4$
}
```

service definition is:

```
define service {
name                           Laborer Clutser check
service_description            laborer_cluster
hostgroup_name                 laborer_cluster
use                            generic-http-1min
check_command                  check_cluster!@40!@60!"laborer cluster"!$SERVICESTATEID:cs01:laborer-http$,$SERVICESTATEID:cs02:laborer-http$,$SERVICESTATEID:cs03:laborer-http$,..$SERVICESTATEID:csNN:laborer-http$
```

but for some reason it goes WARN with just one host in a non-ok state:

[warns with one non-ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaXIZ.png)